# cpu.c:253: x264_cpu_detect: Assertion

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg

environment:
    ubuntu 16.04_x64 server
    install ffmpeg through apt-get install
    python 3

when I try

`from moviepy.editor import *
clip = VideoFileClip("/root/video.mp4")
clip.ipython_display(width=280)`

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/moviepy/video/io/html_tools.py", line 219, in ipython_display
    center=center, rd_kwargs=rd_kwargs, **html_kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/moviepy/video/io/html_tools.py", line 97, in html_embed
    clip.write_videofile(**kwargs)
  File "", line 2, in write_videofile
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/moviepy/decorators.py", line 54, in requires_duration
    return f(clip, *a, **k)
  File "", line 2, in write_videofile
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/moviepy/decorators.py", line 137, in use_clip_fps_by_default
    return f(clip, *new_a, **new_kw)
  File "", line 2, in write_videofile
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/moviepy/decorators.py", line 22, in convert_masks_to_RGB
    return f(clip, *a, **k)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/moviepy/video/VideoClip.py", line 349, in write_videofile
    progress_bar=progress_bar)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_writer.py", line 216, in ffmpeg_write_video
    writer.write_frame(frame)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_writer.py", line 178, in write_frame
    raise IOError(error)
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

MoviePy error: FFMPEG encountered the following error while writing file **temp**.mp4:

ffmpeg: common/cpu.c:253: x264_cpu_detect: Assertion `!(cpu&(0x0000040|0x0000080))' failed.

what happend?

---

@Ronald S. Bultje

**I am using a virtual machine**

processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 13
model name  : QEMU Virtual CPU version (cpu64-rhel6)
stepping    : 3
microcode   : 0x1
cpu MHz     : 3504.000
cache size  : 4096 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 1
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 1
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm rep_good nopl eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 xsaveopt
bugs        :
bogomips    : 7008.00
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

Answer (score 2):

See the [code](http://git.videolan.org/?p=x264.git;a=blob;f=common/cpu.c;h=863818628b4c027c78fcff55838ec96e4af8fdad;hb=HEAD#l244), you appear to have a special (unexpected) type of processor (pentium-M, but one with SSSE3/SSE4 support). I'd get on IRC (freenode: #x264dev) or the [mailinglist](https://mailman.videolan.org/listinfo/x264-devel) and ask the developers to fix it. Also provide the output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo`.

[update]

Reflecting your cpuinfo, x264 indeed doesn't always work if the cpuinfo is "broken", and your qemu setup doesn't reflect an existing chip. I guess I agree that x264 shouldn't really break (there's no reason), so [here](http://git.videolan.org/?p=x264/x264-sandbox.git;a=blobdiff;f=common/cpu.c;h=b9e25d9cda08be7d728cbd58d71a11e92cdfda58;hp=003c9284ed201868ef4bf4b439804a79184ba8be;hb=36593d4c39374d5cd66ef2b4026568f49f539fc2;hpb=9272054abe244b06dd933fca741193f764bde901) is a patch to fix it going forward. However, for your current version, I would simply change the model in your qemu setup (`-cpu` option, I believe) to accurately reflect that it is a Haswell.